# When I first install Ubuntu22, the CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. Power off or reset the virtual machine

Tags: grub2

I'm sure that i had opened the relative settings in Bios,for I can use the Ubuntu 22 on VMWARE.I've done a lot of experiments，but it's difficult to solve.
I doubt that my Ubuntu init has some questions.
at first,it shows error-2 .When I open grub,the /etc/fstab is missing.

Could anyone help me to install Ubuntu 22?

[image]